# Detect if all content is loaded in a Single Page app

Tags: javascript, dom

I am looking for a JS event that I can use to detect if all content is loaded on SPA(like graphs, dynamic data).

I tried load event as well as checked the Dom status(document.readyState) which is not going to help with SPA, so what are the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

The ready state would be window.onLoad

In HTML you could do  `<body onload="myFunction()">`

or

```
object.onload = function(){myScript};
```

check [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) for more info.

Comment: That W3 reference is actually pretty bad, since `onload()` is not supported on every element nor object. Use this one instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: Thanks for sharing the preferred methodology. Although the example you provided also uses window.onLoad

Can you explain the difference please?

Comment: It specifies the objects which support onload.